# Is there a "free" way for testing on different OSes?

Tags: windows, macos, testing, operating-system, virtualization

Is there any "**free**" way to test your software/programs on any other OS. example: Mac OSX, WinXP, ...? (only for testing purposes) Virtualization, maybe?

Comment: Are you talking about web apps or desktop?  Screenshots of rendering or the ability to test functionality?

Comment: @Dallas No, I am simply looking for OS images, for testing purposes. Do you know any links or places for this?

Comment: @Dallas I think there should be official OSes with features disabled but specially for testing programs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are free Windows with Internet Explorer images for Microsoft Virtual PC [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575).

Comment: thanks. I have been looking for "images" like these. Will these work in VirtualBox?

Comment: @Joe DF I am not sure, but I think it does support this format.

Comment: they are designed for Microsoft Virtual PC.  Virtualbox does indeed support the VHD file format and _should_ be able to read them.  however last time I tried this I could not start the Windows instance because the hardware abstraction was different.  Basically it is like moving a hard drive from one computer to another.  If your hardware is compatible no problem but if not you can be in a world of hurt !